# Python tkinter issue. Trouble with del command

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, del

The code should make red oval after hitting UP key and then delete it after certain time. However the red circle remains present.
The point is I wanted to make this circle flash red after hitting UP key and then come back to green. What did I missed?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, CENTER
import time

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
root.title("gui")

gpio_01 = "green"

def gpio_trigger_up(event):
    for i in range(2):
        print "Move Forward"
        time.sleep(0.1) 
    for i in range(1):    
        print "Stop"
        led_01 = gpio.create_oval(160,10,190,40, fill="red")
        return  led_01
        time.sleep(1)
        del led_01
        time.sleep(0.1)

gpio = Canvas()
textfont = "Helvetica"
gpio.create_oval(160,10,190,40, fill=(gpio_01))
gpio.pack()

root.bind("<Up>", gpio_trigger_up)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't use `del` to delete a canvas item, you use [`canvas.delete`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method). (I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer, because your problem isn't as easily solved as "replace this line with that one". Generally speaking, Tkinter does not play nice with `sleep`, so you're going to need to do some extensive redesigning (probably involving `root.after()`) in order to get the proper time-delayed behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning led_01? It breaks out of the function. And the line

```
del led_01
```

Is never reached. Remove the return statement.

Furthermore, you should change the delete line to

```
gpio.delete(led_01)
```

Also, sorry for this being an answer, I don't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: I have made some amendments to the code and still red circle is not flashing red for 0.5s.

Comment: 'code'(def clear():
    gpio.delete("all")
    print "delete all"
    return gpio.create_oval(160,10,190,40, fill=(gpio_01))

def gpio_trigger_up(event):
    led_01_status = 1
    print "Move forward"
    if led_01_status > 0:
        gpio.create_oval(160,10,190,40, fill="red")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print led_01_status
        print "led_01 status is ON"
        led_01_status = 0
    if led_01_status == 0:
        clear()
        time.sleep(0.2)
gpio = Canvas()
gpio.create_oval(160,10,190,40, fill=(gpio_01))
gpio.pack()

root.bind("<Up>", gpio_trigger_up))'code'

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem:

```
def gpio_trigger_up(event):
    print "Move Forward"
    led_01 = gpio.create_oval(160,10,190,40, fill="red")
    gpio.update() 
    time.sleep(0.3)
    gpio.delete(led_01)
```